# Laptop Freezes after unlocking cryptdata following Ubuntu Update

Tags: boot

My laptop freezes after I unlock cryptdata, following trying to update Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The message "cryptsetup (cryptdata): set up successfully" displays but nothing else occurs and I can't reach the standard login screen, nor can I switch to a terminal.

I had been running Ubuntu 18.04, but I notice that on initial startup my laptop gave pop_os options, so I would select:

Pop_Os (Pop_Os-current) - which would take me to the cryptdata login, from which I would then reach my user login into Ubuntu. My terminal would list username@pop-os, but checking prior to updating showed a "current ubuntu version 18.04), and visually my set up appeared to be Ubuntu rather than pop-os.

Any advice would be appreciated! - While I don't have a system back up from before the update, I did back up all of my important files. I would prefer not to have reinstall everything but will if needed. And I would like to be back in Ubuntu since it's what I'm used to now!

Thanks!